# Java Treemap put method

Tags: java, dictionary

I wrote this method. I don't understand why it is write out this exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: Kocsma.Sör cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable

Anybody know what is my mistake?

The compiler reference this line

> beers.put(beer, dl);

This is my code:

```
private Map<Beer, Integer> beers = new TreeMap<Beer, Integer>();


public void Upload(Beer beer, int dl) {
    int d = 0;
    Beer s = null;
    for (Map.Entry<Beer, Integer> item : beers.entrySet()) {
        if (item.getKey().equals(beer)) {
            d = item.getValue();
            s = item.getKey();
        }
    }
    if (s != null) {
        beers.put(s, d + dl);
    }else
    beers.put(beer, dl); // Here is the problem by the Compiler
}
```

Class Kocsma:

```
public Kocsma() {
    Upload(new Beer("Borsodi sör", 160, 4.6), 1000);
    Upload(new Beer("Pilsner Urquell", 250, 4.4), 800);
    Upload(new Beer("Soproni Ászok", 150, 4.5), 900);
    Upload(new Beer("Dreher Classic", 200, 5.2), 600);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `Beer` class needs to implement `Comparable<Beer>` or you need to provide a `Comparator<Beer>` to the `TreeMap` constructor.

```
private static class BeerComparator implements Comparator<Beer> {
     @Override
     public int compare(Beer b1, Beer b2) {
         //return a value > 1 if b1 is greater than b2, < 1 if b2 greater than b1,
         //and exactly 0 if the two are equal
     }
}

beers = new TreeMap<Beer, Integer>(new BeerComparator());
```

`TreeMap` stores keys by using a binary search tree.  This works without effort for some common classes like `Integer` and `String`  because they are naturally sortable and implement `Comparable` out of the box.  However, for your `Beer` class, you would have to implement it manually.

If `Beer` is not a good candidate for comparisons (most things aren't) then consider using `HashMap` instead, and overriding `equals()` and `hashCode()` on `Beer` (see [*Effective Java* Chapter 3](http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/effectivejava/) for a great reference on this).

Comment: Yes-yes, but I still don't understand, why it have to Comparable. Because it is only an add method...

Comment: Oh, cause TreeMap stores keys like the bst?

Comment: @blaces that's correct.  It uses a red-black tree implementation

Answer (score 1):

First, `Beer` must implement the `Comparable` interface if you want to put it in a `TreeMap`. But why do you want a `TreeMap`? You could just use a `HashMap`.

Also your code might look much simpler:

```
private Map<Beer, Integer> beers = new HashMap<Beer, Integer>();

public void Upload(Beer beer, int dl) {
   Integer d  = beers.get(beer);
   if (d != null) {
    beers.put(beer, d + dl);
   }else
    beers.put(beer, dl);
}
```

In any case you might want to overwrite the `equals()` (and `hashCode()`) method in `Beer`, so that it equals on its name for example.